# Load URL on window load in Swift

Tags: swift, webview, xcode6

I'm trying to load a URL in my WebView in Swift as soon as the main dialog loads. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
class WebViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WebView!

    // constants
    let webUrl = "https://www.google.com"
    let webUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: webUrl)!)
        request.setValue(webUA, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

When debugging there are no errors or warnings. I think I linked the nib with the objects properly:

[image]
[image]

I've been playing around with delegations for a few hours now. The page simply doesn't load.

At first I attempted to use `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, but that went even worse, because the WebView was never finished being created and was `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was pointing to the wrong WebView?!

In the hierarchy, it shows up like this:[image]

I needed to use the one that's highlighted, not the inner one. The inner one was used when I control-dragged from Objects into the physical view object in the layout builder. Somehow dragging to this one fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so change your ViewController to look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var urlPath = "http://www.google.com"

    func loadAddressUrl() {
        let requestUrl = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestUrl!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        loadAddressUrl()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

And link the @IBOutlet to your web view controller. Example project available if you want.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rva9ylPHi2w

Comment: I'm using the OS X equivalent of UIKit which is AppKit so the names are a bit different, but essentially, this is pretty much the same code. I did try adding weak to the webView IBOutlet but that didn't change anything. Also it was already linked, as par my screenshots (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure how AppKit works, but why does the webUA have to be there? It looks like you could get rid of that and the request.setValue line, sorry I can't be much help.

Comment: It's because google.com isn't the actual website I'm going to, and it doesn't like Safari. It's not the point though, because I removed that part for testing and it still didn't work. Thanks for taking the time to try though :)

Answer (score 0):

Swfit 4 version of loadAddressUrl()

```
private func loadAddressUrl() {
    let requestUrl = NSURL(string: url.text!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestUrl! as URL)
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)
}
```